# operations on dictionary

Tags: python, loops, sorting, dictionary

I have 2 dictionaries `dict 1` and `dict 2`

`dict1` is the original dictionary of model scores from an Ml model and `dict2` is the modified score based on some condition. In `dict2` , i am basically overridding the model score based on some condition , so any number of keys can have their scores as 1.0 , it is also possible that no scores gets overrirdded. so in that case `dict1 = dict 2`
i want to create the output_dict such that if more than 1 keys have their scores overridden to 1.0, i want to give 1.0 to the score with higher original score.
The length of dict1 and dict2 will be same , in below example i have kept it as 4, but in real work it could be anything.

```
dict1 = {'A':0.78, 'B':0.64, 'C':0.67, 'D':0.56}
dict2 = {'A':0.78, 'B':1.0, 'C':1.0, 'D':0.56}
```

```
outout_dict ={'A':0.78,'B':0.64,'C':1.0,'D':0.56}
```

For example, in above example both `'B'` and `'C'` had their scores as 1.0 but only C's score is kept as 1.0 in `output_dict` because it had higher probability in `dict1`

Is there an elegant pythonic way of doing it, i am stuck in lot of for and if loops

```
dict1 = {'A':0.78, 'B':0.64, 'C':0.67, 'D':0.56}
dict2 = {'A':0.78, 'B':1.0, 'C':1.0, 'D':0.56}
keys =[]
for key,value in dict2.items():
    if value == 1.0:
        keys.append(key)
#keys = ['B', 'C']
        
for k,v in dict1:
    if
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dict1 = {'A': 0.78, 'B': 0.64, 'C': 0.67, 'D': 0.56}
dict2 = {'A': 0.78, 'B': 1.0, 'C': 1.0, 'D': 0.56}
Lowestchange = [1.00 ,""]
for key in dict1:
   if(dict2[key] - dict1[key] < Lowestchange[0] and dict2[key] != dict1[key] ):
       Lowestchange = [dict2[key] - dict1[key] , key]
if(Lowestchange[1] != ""):
 dict1[Lowestchange[1]] = dict2[Lowestchange[1]]
print(dict1)
```